# Interruptible multiprocessing pool workers (python)

Tags: python, architecture, python-multiprocessing

I have python GUI application which can kick off any number of computation-intensive long-running tasks that naturally belong in `multiprocessing.Pool` workers.

However, I'd like to be able to cancel these tasks, because later GUI input (such as changing a configuration variable) might render these tasks irrelevant.

**Is there a popular pattern in Python for keeping track of which workers are working on what task, and interrupting them as needed?**

The solutions I can think of are:

1. When a worker starts on a task it "announces" through some shared state that it is working on that particular task; if we need to cancel that task we look up which process is working on it and `.terminate()` it. There are many complexities here though.
2. Use raw `multiprocessing.Process`es and write a `Pool`-like manager that does exactly what we want.
3. Use some alternative library such as Celery. A huge list is [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing).